# How to delay show/hide of bootstrap-tooltips?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble making that data-delay attribute of twitter bootstrap tooltips work. I am using it like :

Here is how i use it :

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-delay="{ show: 5000, hide: 3000}">with delay</a>
<script>
    jQuery('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip().click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
</script>
```

but i don't see any delay on show/hide. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Finally I got it working with data attribute.

```
data-delay='{"show":"5000", "hide":"3000"}'
```

The object must be surrounded by single quotes, keys with double quotes and values with double or none, probably depends on the type. Is the only way that works.

This works for popovers too.

Comment: The `data-delay` attribute appears to be in JSON format, which is why you evidently have to double quote the key name. FYI, you do not have to quote the integers values if you don't want, e.g. `data-delay='{"show": 100, "hide": 1000}'`

Comment: `data-delay='{"show": 100, "hide": 1000}'` and `data-delay='{"show":"5000", "hide":"3000"}'` aren't doing anything for me. Has this worked for anyone else?

Comment: Confirmed, doesn't work here either, Bootstrap 3.3.4

Comment: Works for me, with and without the quotes. I suspect knowing it's JSON might solve a bunch of other odd corner cases.

Comment: Not working with B5. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72695891/bootstrap-5-0-2-tooltip-data-bs-delay-attribute-problem.

Comment: On B5 just add "bs" like other attribute: `data-bs-delay='{"show":"5000", "hide":"3000"}'`, it works for me

Answer (score 31):

Why can't you do it like this?

```
$('a').tooltip({
     'delay': { show: 5000, hide: 3000 }
});
```

Comment: it gives me an unexpected token : error for some reason, probably an error in the syntax or so.

Comment: This does work, but it doesn't answer the original question of how to get it working with the data attribute.

Comment: @Pepper actually he did'nt mentioned that he need to wrok with `data` attribute.right..?

Comment: @Gautam3164 the title says `Data delay`, and he says that is having trouble on making `data-delay attribute` work. So it kinda mention that he wants to use `data attribute`.

Comment: @azeós `but i don't see any delay on show/hide` can you see this.It is not working for him.That's why I have given the ans...He also accepted it even..But its not that bad to down it

Comment: @Gautam3164 I'm alright with your answer, I just posted mine a couple of months ago because I couldn't find this information in SO and I thought it could be useful for someone else. You are right, it doesn't seems mandatory for the OP to use data attribute, but he tried and couldn't; that's why I answered it.

Comment: Even now you can remove the down I think..? ;-)

Comment: the other answer -- data-delay='{"show":"5000", "hide":"3000"}'  -- is much better.

Comment: BTW both are same.mine using jQuery and his ans deals with HTML.That's it

Comment: Only works if you want to use jQuery. Doesn't answer the question if you need to use this in a data-attribute. This answer shouldn't be correct.

Comment: @BryceJohnson then why he did tagged for `jQuery`?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'delay': { show: 5000, hide: 3000 }
    });   
});
```

Comment: I like that since you need the js function anyway, can make a good argument for just putting all or most of the config in one place.

Comment: When I use Javascript  `delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 0 }` it's not working in Andriod chrome

Answer (score 4):

your answer doesn't work with Bootstrap 3.3.2.
This one working well for my version:

```
data-delay='{"show":5000, "hide":3000}'
```

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13874

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delay the show and hide for the same amount of time you can just add this when using BS5

```
data-bs-delay="500"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<div ... popover-popup-delay="2000" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

For use with AngularJS (UI):

```
<div tooltip="Hello" tooltip-popup-delay="500"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround!

Couldn't get it to work for my info message popover on a modal but used this workaround in my JavaScript:

```
$('#infoPopover').attr("data-original-title", "Delete Document");
$('#infoPopover').attr("data-content", "Success");
$('#infoPopover').popover('show');
setTimeout(function () { $('#infoPopover').popover('hide') }, 4000);
```

It works on an empty span...

```
<span id="infoPopover" data-toggle="popover"></span>
```

popover shows for a few seconds then hides again.

[Image of popover info message on a modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb7gF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling here after September 2023 or using Bootstrap 5.2+, the `data-tooltip` works but I didn't manage to change the `show` or `hide` with the provided answer.

To make it work, follow the documentation:

```
data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-title="My tooltip" data-bs-delay='{"show":0,"hide":150}'
```