# Bootstrap 5.0.2 tooltip data-bs-delay attribute problem

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Having problems with BS 5.0.2 tooltip show and hide delay.
[According to BS documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/) it's possible to setup the show and hide delay in attribute as an object like below:

```
data-bs-delay:{show:2000, hide:1000}
```

or

```
data-bs-delay={show:2000, hide:1000}
```

But the tooltip is shown/hidden without any delay or the console shows `"Uncaught TypeError: TOOLTIP: Option "delay" provided type "string" but expected type "(number|object)"`."

While setting up only

```
data-bs-delay=2000
```

gives the delay but it's the same for show and hide.

So far I have tried all quotation marks variations in the attribute as suggested on the internet but to no joy.
I have come across solutions for that but using jquery which is something I'm not interested ATM.

Is it possible to set up the different times for tooltip show and hide delay in the attributes?

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 5em;
  width: 15em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id="container" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
    data-bs-html="true" data-bs-delay='{"show":2000, "hide":1000}' 
    title="Delayed tooltip.">Hover here to show a tooltip after 2 seconds and to hide it after 1 second</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Well that's super annoying, now innit? I even tried updating the library to 5.1 (which you should do if you can--should be painless). No luck.

Comment: Related (but unhelpful): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170967/how-to-delay-show-hide-of-bootstrap-tooltips

Answer (score 5):

I'm yet to find a way to achieve this using the `data-bs-delay` attribute however have found a way to have a global delay for every tooltip (which I think works better) with the below code

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl,{delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 100 }});
})
```

The second argument for `bootstrap.Tooltip(element,config)` is a `config` object in which I would assume you could override any of the default values below (I've only tested the `delay` option)

```
const Default = {
  animation: true,
  template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip">' +
              '<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>' +
              '<div class="tooltip-inner"></div>' +
            '</div>',
  trigger: 'hover focus',
  title: '',
  delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 100 },
  html: false,
  selector: false,
  placement: 'top',
  offset: [0, 0],
  container: false,
  fallbackPlacements: ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'],
  boundary: 'clippingParents',
  customClass: '',
  sanitize: true,
  sanitizeFn: null,
  allowList: DefaultAllowlist,
  popperConfig: null
}
```

I'm no JS expert however this little hack did the job for me :)

Comment: This solution is nice. However, one can still use the custom delay values, instead of setting them globally (on every tooltip). Check the `tooltipTriggerEl` if it has `data-bs-delay` attribute, extract the delay values, remove the attribute, and pass the values to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a delay to a tooltip and came across this problem.

I have the simple `index.html` page below. When I double-click on the file and run it (with the url: `file:///C:/.../test/index.html`), the delay and the tooltip seem to work. However, when I access the file/folder from the localhost  (with the url: `http://localhost/test/`), I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: TOOLTIP: Option "delay" provided type "string" but expected type "(number|object)".

I tried to debug the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` file, and at the surface, there does not appear to be a problem. To manually inspect the file, I switched to `bootstrap.bundle.js`, and the problem went away. Now, both the `file:///C:/.../test/index.html` and `http://localhost/test/` work.

I can't make sense of this. Why would the minified .js file not work when served via http/localhost? Well, I'm not that curious. Getting it to work was enough.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blank HTML5 Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/ext/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="p-4">

<span
    class="d-inline-block"
    tabindex="0"
    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
    data-bs-title="Disabled tooltip"
    data-bs-delay='{"show":1000,"hide":200}'
    >
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> button</button>
</span>


<script src="../assets/ext/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
    tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
    tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: Used Bootstrap v5.3.2